# Как сохранить список из LatLng при повороте экрана?

Tags: android, google-maps

В главной активности имеется фрагмент отображающий карту с нанесенными маркерами. Перед построением маршрута я отмечаю какое-то кол-во местоположений (заполняю список `List<LatLng>`). Как можно сохранить значение списка при повороте экрана, если `LatLng` не `Serializable`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LatLng` реализует интерфейс `Parcelable`, воспользуйтесь методом `putParcelableArrayList`

---

```
ArrayList<LatLng> latLngList = new ArrayList<>();
savedInstanceState.putParcelableArrayList("latlng", latLngList);
```

Comment: да, верно подмечено